# Nav2 DWB local planner over-correcting at goal

Tags: navigation, ros2, nav2, 2d-nav-goal, dwa

I have a differential drive robot application that requires a relatively tight `xy_goal_tolerance` of 3-4 cm. Usually if the goal heading is close to the robot's approach heading, the tolerance can be met. However, if a large rotation is required at the goal (i.e. to meet `yaw_goal_tolerance` requirements), then the robot is usually unable to meet the `xy_goal_tolerance`. This occurs due to localization updates during the rotation "pushing" the robot out of its `xy_goal_tolerance`. This then causes the robot to drive around in circles as it tries to get back within `xy_goal_tolerance` requirements, which isn't great behavior.

To try and solve this issue, I'm trying to do the following:

1. Have the robot approach the goal and try to meet the `xy_goal_tolerance`
2. Once `xy_goal_tolerance` is met, ignore the `xy_goal_tolerance` and perform the final rotation to meet the `yaw_goal_tolerance` requirement.

This will forgo meeting the `xy_goal_tolerance` if we're required to do a large final rotation, but it will prevent the "over-corrective" behavior currently seen in the robot where it circles its goal like a shark.

I tried using the `stateful = True` parameter in the `SimpleGoalChecker`, which from the description seems to achieve what I want (i.e. approach goal to meet `xy_goal_tolerance`, then once `xy_goal_tolerance` is met, ignore it and meet `yaw_goal_tolerance` requirement), but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Is this a bug in the `SimpleGoalChecker`, or am I missing what `stateful` actually does? Any help would be great, thanks very much.

**EDIT:**
Looking closer at the code, I think the `stateful` parameter is not working as expected because I am using a BT that performs global path replanning at 1 Hz, which always resets the `SimpleGoalChecker`.

In the `ControllerServer::setPlannerPath()` function, we have

```
goal_checkers_[current_goal_checker_]->reset();
```

which resets the `SimpleGoalChecker` whenever the global plan is replanned. Putting an if statement around this to only reset the goal checker when the *goal changes* instead of when the global plan is replanned, makes the `stateful` parameter work as expected (i.e. the local planner first meets the `xy_goal_tolerance` and once this is met it ignores `xy_goal_tolerance` while it meets the `yaw_goal_tolerance`).

However, since the `RotateToGoal` critic also uses an `xy_goal_tolerance`, it will "fight" with the `SimpleGoalChecker` and still cause the local planner to over-correct near the goal if tight tolerances are used. If I modify this critic to be stateful like the `SimpleGoalChecker`, and modify the `DWBLocalPlanner::setPlan()` function by putting an if statement around the lines

```
  for (TrajectoryCritic::Ptr & critic : critics_) {
    critic->reset();
  }
```

to only reset if the goal changes, then this solves the issue and the robot does a "two-step" goal approach process where it first meets the `xy_goal_tolerance` and then meets the `yaw_goal_tolerance` independent of the `xy_goal_tolerance`. This allows me to get within 2-3 cm of the goal quite consistently.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what "doesn't seem to work as expected" means. What do you observe?

Comment: Hi @Mike973, I think I mentioned what this means in the sentences "This then causes the robot to drive around in circles as it tries to get back within xy_goal_tolerance requirements" and "will prevent the "over-corrective" behavior currently seen in the robot is it circles its goal like a shark." and "approach goal to meet xy_goal_tolerance, then once xy_goal_tolerance is met, ignore it and meet yaw_goal_tolerance requirement"

Comment: For some reason SE isn't allowing me to edit my post. I get the vague message "An error occurred submitting the edit".

Comment: I deleted my answer because after checking the source code, my answer was not correct. "True" is the value you want, and it is the default. So either your robot never gets close enough to the goal, or some condition is resetting the SimpleGoalChecker. Have you tried increasing x,y goal tolerance just to see what happens?

Comment: Thanks @Mike973, yes it looks like global replanning was constantly resetting the SimpleGoalChecker, and I also had to modify the RotateToGoal critic to be stateful and also not reset. This solved my issue (see EDIT section in my post above for details).

Comment: I think you should create an answer with the key points from your edit. It's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

> Once xy_goal_tolerance is met, ignore the xy_goal_tolerance and perform the final rotation to meet the yaw_goal_tolerance requirement.

Within Nav2's DWB, this is referred to as the `stateful` parameter, which is available in all ROS 2 distributions for you to use. When that is set to true, once the XY tolerance is met, it keeps that *state* and then rotates in place for the yaw tolerance!

What doesn't work as expected? What's your ROS distribution?

Comment: It looks like global replanning was constantly resetting the SimpleGoalChecker, and I also had to modify the RotateToGoal critic to be stateful and also not reset when global replanning was performed. This solved my issue (see EDIT section in my question for details).

Comment: @indigoblue can you submit that as a PR so we can fix that in mainline for everyone?